# Generated RSS shows markdown syntax

Tags: jekyll

I have a problem with Jekyll and the RSS. When I publish a new post at my blog, if you use a RSS agregator you can see the post perfectly formated.

But when I post to other places (Telegram in this case) this happens:
[image]

As you can see it shows markdown's syntax.

This is in my _config.yml (I don't know if it affects to something):
permalink: /:year/:month/:day/:title/

```
# Build settings
markdown: kramdown

# Old config
highlighter: pygments
```

How does it happen?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Did you have a repository url ?

Comment: @DavidJacquel No, I got Jekyll on my server, I don't user GitHub Pages

Comment: Try to change from pygments to rouge and see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

I encounter the same problem using Jekyll 3.1.2 if the _site directory is non-empty and I edit the feed.xml template.

With a clean start the feed.xml is generated correctly.